# IOS SwiftUI - @main -> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee1a57ff0)

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swiftui, thread-safety

In the code below you can see the error and the code used in my xxApp.swift folder.

I was creating Sign In and a Sign Up function, and everything worked very well, but then I got this error when clicking on the register button.

If you need more code just let me know, thanks in advance!

Here is the code :

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}


final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}`final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
}
@main -> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee1a57ff0)"
struct PSMAApp: App {
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
@StateObject var sessionService = SessionServiceImpl()
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView{
switch sessionService.state {
            case .loggedIn:
                HomeView()
                    .environmentObject(sessionService)
case .loggedOut:
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Here is the register Button - ViewModel :

```
import Foundation
import Combine
enum RegistrationState {
case successfull
case failed(error: Error)
case na
}

protocol RegistrationViewModel {
func register()
var hasError: Bool { get }
var  service: RegistrationService { get }
var state: RegistrationState { get }
var userDetails: RegistrationDetails { get }
init(service: RegistrationService)
}

final class RegistrationViewModelImpl: ObservableObject, RegistrationViewModel {

@Published var hasError: Bool = false
@Published var state: RegistrationState = .na

let service: RegistrationService
var userDetails: RegistrationDetails = RegistrationDetails.new

private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init(service: RegistrationService) {
    self.service = service
    setupErrorSubscriptions()
}
func register() {
    
    service
        .register(with: userDetails)
        .sink { [weak self] res in
            switch res {
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.state = .failed(error: error)
            default: break
            }
        } receiveValue: { [weak self] in
                self?.state = .successfull
            }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}

private extension RegistrationViewModelImpl {

func setupErrorSubscriptions() {
    
    $state
        .map { state -> Bool in
            switch state {
            case .successfull,
                 .na:
                return false
            case .failed:
                return true
            }
        }
        .assign(to: &$hasError)
}
}
```

Here is Register - RegistrationService :

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

enum RegistrationKeys: String {
case username
}

protocol RegistrationService {
func register(with details: RegistrationDetails) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error>
}

final class RegistrationServiceImpl: RegistrationService {
func register(with details: RegistrationDetails) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    
    Deferred {
        Future { promise in
            
            Auth.auth()
                .createUser(withEmail: details.email,
                            password: details.password) {res, error in
                    
                    if let err = error {
                        promise(.failure(err))
                    } else {
                        
                        if let uid = res?.user.uid {
                            let values = [
                            RegistrationKeys.username.rawValue: details.username] as [String : Any]
                            
                        Database.database()
                                .reference()
                                .child("users")
                                .child(uid)
                                .updateChildValues(values) {
                                    error, ref in
                                    
                                    if let err = error {
                                        promise(.failure(err))
                                    } else {
                                        promise(.success(()))
                                    }
                                }
                            
                        } else {
                            promise(.failure(NSError(domain: "Invalid user ID", code: 0, userInfo: nil)))
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
}
```

Here is Registraion - SessionService :

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

enum SessionState {
case loggedIn
case loggedOut
}

protocol SessionService {
var state: SessionState { get }
var userDetails: SessionUserDetails? { get }
func logout()
}

final class SessionServiceImpl: ObservableObject, SessionService {

@Published var state: SessionState = .loggedOut
@Published var userDetails: SessionUserDetails?

private var handler: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

init() {
    setupFirebaseAuthHandler()
}

func logout() {
    try? Auth.auth().signOut()
}

}

private extension SessionServiceImpl {

func setupFirebaseAuthHandler() {
    
    handler = Auth
        .auth()
        .addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] res, user in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.state = user == nil ? .loggedOut : .loggedIn
            if let uid = user?.uid {
                self.handleRefresh(with: uid)
            }
        }
}

    func handleRefresh(with uid: String) {
    
    Database
        .database()
        .reference()
        .child("users")
        .child(uid)
        .observe(.value) { [weak self] snapshot in
            
            guard let self = self,
                  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary,
                  let username = value[RegistrationKeys.username.rawValue] as? String else{
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.userDetails = SessionUserDetails(username: username)
            }
            
        }
    
}
```

}

Here is the Register - Model :

```
struct RegistrationDetails {
var email: String
var username: String
var password: String
}

extension RegistrationDetails {



static var new: RegistrationDetails {
    
    RegistrationDetails(email: "",
                        username: "",
                        password: "")
    
}
}
```

Here is the Registration - View :

```
import SwiftUI

struct RegisterView: View {


@StateObject private var vm = RegistrationViewModelImpl(
    service: RegistrationServiceImpl()
)
 var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        
        VStack(spacing: 32) {
            VStack(spacing: 16) {
                
                InputTextFieldView(text: $vm.userDetails.email,
                                  placeholder: "Email",
                                  keyboardType: .emailAddress,
                                  sfSymbol: "envelope")
                
                 InputPasswordView(password: $vm.userDetails.password,
                                   placeholder: "Password",
                                    sfSymbol: "lock")
                
                Divider()
                
                 InputTextFieldView(text: $vm.userDetails.username,
                                   placeholder: "Username",
                                   keyboardType: .namePhonePad,
                                   sfSymbol: nil)

            }
ButtonComponentView(title: "Sign up") {
                vm.register()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
        .navigationTitle("Register")
        .applyClose()
        .alert(isPresented: $vm.hasError,
            content: {
                if case .failed(let error) = vm.state {
                    return Alert(
                        title: Text("Error"),
                        message: Text(error.localizedDescription))
                } else {
                    return Alert(
                        title: Text("Error"),
                        message: Text("Something went wrong"))
            }
        })
    }
    
}
}

struct RegisterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    RegisterView()
        .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
}
}
```

Comment: you'll need to show more code, especially the troublesome register button

Comment: Yes, will add the code of the button, but the problem just shows of at the @main. The rest works fine and the users are registered at the firebase database. I will post the register button but for the rest it is too much code to post.